# How I can update boolean field in DynamoDb with Mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have next code for update item in DB with mapping template:

```
 $!{expSet.put("available", ":available")}
 $!{expValues.put(":available", { "BOOL": $ctx.args.available })}
```

when I send available = false  - it's ok, but if available = true I get error

> "Unable to parse the JSON document: 'Unexpected character (':' (code
>   58)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

schema in GraphQl

```
type Item {
....
    available: Boolean!
....
}
```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Your UpdateItem request mapping template should look something like:

```
{
"version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "UpdateItem",
"key" : {
    "id" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.id}" }
},
"update" : {
    "expression" : "SET #available = :available",
    "expressionNames": {
        "#available" : "available"
    },
    "expressionValues": {
        ":available" : { "BOOL": ${context.arguments.available} }
    }
  }
}
```